# ABI string not working

Tags: c#, ethereum, contracts

I am writing a program which takes an ethereum contract ABI string in C# and uses it to call a function which allows me to interact with the smart contract using nethereum. When I use a smaller ABI string I am able to make it work but for some reason it won't work with this longer string or any other ABI which exceeds the length of a small example ABI. When I compile the code below I get the error message **(*bare in mind that I have tried JSON deserializing but that still makes the same error)***:

**An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code**

**Additional information: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: t. Path '[0].outputs[0].name', line 3, position 20.**

```
protected void init()
{
    web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3();

    string abi = @"[{'constant':false,'inputs':[{'name':'username','type':'string'},
    {'name':'location','type':'string'}],'name':'addUser','outputs':
    [{'name':','type':'string'}],'type':'function'},{'constant':false,'inputs'
    :[],'name':'burnCoins','outputs':[{'name':','type':'uint256'}],'type':'function'},
    {'constant':false,'inputs':[{'name':'vendor','type':'address'},
    {'name':'recipient','type':'address'}],'name':'trade','outputs':[],
    'type':'function'},{'constant':false,'inputs':[{'name':'vendor','type':'address'},
    {'name':'isPositive','type':'bool'},{'name':'message','type':'string'}],
    'name':'giveReputation','outputs':[],'type':'function'},{'constant':false,'inputs':
    [{'name':'user','type':'address'}],'name':'showBurnedCoins','outputs':[{'name':
    ','type':'uint256'}],'type':'function'},{'constant':false,'inputs':[{'name':'user',
    'type':'address'}],'name':'viewReputation','outputs':[{'name':','type':'uint256'},
    {'name':','type':'uint256'},{'name':','type':'uint256'}],'type':'function'},
    {'anonymous':false,'inputs':[{'indexed':true,'name':'user','type':'address'},
    {'indexed':true,'name':'amountBurned','type':'uint256'}],'name':'_coinsBurned',
    'type':'event'},{'anonymous':false,'inputs':[{'indexed':true,'name':'user',
    'type':'address'},{'indexed':true,'name':'message','type':'string'}],'
    name':'_positiveReputation','type':'event'},{'anonymous':false,'inputs'
    :[{'indexed':true,'name':'user','type':'address'},{'indexed':true,'name':'message'
    ,'type':'string'}],'name':'_negativeReputation','type':'event'},
    {'anonymous':false,'inputs':[{'indexed':true,'name':'username','type':'string'},
    {'indexed':true,'name':'location','type':'string'},{'indexed':true,'name':
    'user','type':'address'}],'name':'_addUser','type':'event'},{'anonymous':false,
    'inputs':[{'indexed':true,'name':'vendor','type':'address'},{'indexed':true,
    'name':'buyer','type':'address'}],'name':'_newTrade','type':'event'},{'anonymous':
    false,'inputs':[{'indexed':true,'name':'user','type':'address'},{'indexed':true,
    'name':'positive','type':'uint256'},{'indexed':true,'name':'negative','type':'uint256'},
    {'indexed':false,'name':'total','type':'uint256'}],'name':'_viewedReputation',
    'type':'event'}]";

    string contractAddress = "0xd53c3dc2f3fcf1779b68ea8e441d857b4af5a413";
    Reputation = web3.Eth.GetContract(abi, contractAddress);
}
```

Comment: The error is because of the line `'name':'showBurnedCouns', 'outputs':[{'name':','type':'uint256'}]`. A `'` is missing inside the `outputs` block.

Comment: @diiN_ Please post your comment as an answer so that this question can be tidied, and you also get the reputation.

Answer (score 3):

From my comment:

The error is because of the line `'name':'showBurnedCouns', 'outputs':[{'name':','type':'uint256'}]`. A `'` is missing inside the outputs block.

Answer (score 0):

See  diiN_ comment on my question as this answers the question. Silly me!